# Which type font would you recommend to mimic the one included in this form from 1950/1960s?

Tags: font-identification

I am looking for a type font which could the one used in this form. It is an old 1950s/1960s font that can be seen here:

[image]

Specifically I am interested in the font used in the different fields of the form (PROGRAM, PROGRAMMER, DATE, FORTRAN STATEMENT" and the numbers.

If the font can be used freely that would be a plus. I have tried myfonts.com but I am not really finding a matching one.

Comment: That’s essentially a variant of Futura, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks, that helps to further dig into other Futura variants. One question I would have is if this one is a variant of Futura or is Futura a variant of this one -given that this is an old font-.

Comment: Futura was first released in 1927, and there have been countless variations of it released by myriad foundries over the decades, so this is presumably just one of those many variations.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet for a nearly 100 years old its still having a bit of futuristic tone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks very close to Futura Medium BT
[image]

https://freefontsfamily.com/futura-font-family-free/

Comment: I would not be surprised if it was a non-bold form of Futura. It was a VERY popular modern sans-serif font in the 50s-60s. I would look for ITC Futura or an older version.